# Comparing an mktime() timestamp with today's date()

Tags: php

I am building a PHP Calendar, and I would like to highlight today with the Bootstrap class `info`. This is my code so far that loops through and displays the days:

```
<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $current_month, 1, $current_year);
$max_day = date("t", $timestamp);
$this_month = getdate($timestamp);
$start_day = $this_month["wday"];

for ($i = 0; $i < ($max_day + $start_day); $i++) {
    if ($i % 7 == 0) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
    }
    if ($i < $start_day) {
        echo "<td></td>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<td class=\"text-center\" style=\"height:100px;valign:middle\">" . ($i - $start_day + 1) . "</td>\n";
    }
    if ($i % 7 == 6) {
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
}
?>
```

I would somehow like to get today's date (with `date()`?) and compare it to the date currently being used within my `for` loop, adding a class to the `<td>` if they match. However, I'm scratching my head trying to figure out exactly how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you compare them using `strtotime()` ? You can turn $max_day into a comparable timestamp like this

`$unix_max_day = strtotime($max_day);` and compare it to `$timestamp`

so for example...

```
if($unix_max_day < $timestamp){
    echo '$max_day is less than $timestamp';
}
```

Hope this is what you meant... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do three checks because the date I am using is in the array `$this_month[]`, one checking the **day** was the same, one checking the **month** was the same, and then one checking the **year** was the same.

Putting my result into a variable `$td` like so:

```
$td = ((($i - $start_day + 1) == date("j")) && ($this_month["mon"] == date("n")) && ($this_month["year"] == date("Y")) ? "info" : "");
```

Who knows if this is the most efficient way of doing it.